# Update excel file when opened if a new version is available

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file which checks its local version with the current version from a database. The code to check the version isn't important to the question.

If there's a new version I want to download it, close the old file (because I can't change/modify it while opened), replace it with the new downloaded version and open the downloaded version.

What I have is something like this:

**file.xlsm**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\update.xlsm"
End Sub
```

**update.xlsm**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Workbooks("file.xlsm").Close
  Dim num As Byte
  Dim WHTTP As Object
  On Error Resume Next
  Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTPrequest.5")
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
  On Error GoTo 0
  WHTTP.Open "GET", "http://path/file.xlsm", False
  WHTTP.Send
  num = FreeFile
  On Error Resume Next
  Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file.xlsm" For Binary Access Write As num
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file.xlsm").Close
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\File.xlsm" For Binary Access Write As num
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
  Put num, , WHTTP.ResponseBody
  Close num
  Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file.xlsm"
  ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

The issue is that since `update.xlsm` was opened from `file.xlsm`, once I close `file.xlsm`, the code from `update.xlsm` stops running.

I found [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fc77123d-349d-48ee-8cb8-8016ce8b3267/vba-to-continue-after-workbook-close?forum=exceldev) which is pretty much what I want to do but I couldn't figure out how to get the `Application.OnTime` working.

[Here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/353006-download-file-excel.html#post1744744)'s where I got the code to download the file.

## Edit:

Ok, so I got it almost fully working with the following:

**server file.xlsm**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  'Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\update.xlsm"
End Sub
```

**local file.xlsm**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\update.xlsm"
End Sub
```

**local update.xlsm**

ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.OnTime Now, "test"
End Sub
```

Module:

```
Sub test()
  Workbooks("file.xlsm").Close
  Dim num As Byte
  Dim WHTTP As Object
  On Error Resume Next
  Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTPrequest.5")
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
  On Error GoTo 0
  WHTTP.Open "GET", "http://path/file.xlsm", False
  WHTTP.Send
  num = FreeFile
  On Error Resume Next
  Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file.xlsm" For Binary Access Write As num
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file.xlsm").Close
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\File.xlsm" For Binary Access Write As num
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
  Put num, , WHTTP.ResponseBody
  Close num
  Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file.xlsm"
  If Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
    Application.Quit
  Else
    ThisWorkbook.Close
  End If
End Sub
```

The problem I'm getting now is the new downloaded file from the server gets corrupted in some way (it works after the message of Excel repairing the file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the Macro in 2 parts, and use OnTime to trigger the second part *first*.  Here is an example:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    On Error GoTo SkipErr
    Application.OnTime Now(), "ThisWorkbook.Part2" 'Run as soon other macros finish
    Workbooks("file.xlsm").Close
SkipErr:
    MsgBox "file.xlsm was not open...", vbCritical
End Sub

Public Sub Part2()
    MsgBox "This message will show!", vbInformation
End Sub
```